# Keyboard Interrupt of subprocess.run()

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I have a Python code in which I use the subprocess.run() in order to call 10 times (iteratively) an outside heavy simulation, the simulation make around 40 iterations. So, I have 10*40 = 400 simulation runs. My problem is that although up to some point the whole process runs smoothly, after a few hours I get an error related to the subprocess.run():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/ChargersDanielWithInput.py", line 63, in <module>
    subprocess.run(["/zhome/c9/f/144817/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn", "exec:java", "-Dexec.mainClass=org.matsim.contrib.ev.example.MyRunEvExample", "-Dexec.args=/work3/s175836/Scenarios/Scenario_1/Input/config_test_daniel.xml", "-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false"])
  File "/appl/python/3.8.4/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 491, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/appl/python/3.8.4/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1016, in communicate
    self.wait()
  File "/appl/python/3.8.4/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1079, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/appl/python/3.8.4/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1804, in _wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/appl/python/3.8.4/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1762, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The very weird thing here, is that this error doesn't pop up at let's say the first call of subprocess.run(), but it happends at some point during the whole simulation process. I really do not have any idea why this happens.
Right now, I have replaced the subprocess.run() with os.system() wanting to actually double-check that it's the subprocess.run() command which brings up the trouble.

Comment: Did you try without the timeout option? You can also try to use Popen()/communicate() directly, which are at lower level than run(), but are part of modern API than os.system()

Comment: @BingWang I haven't edited anything in the subprocess, so no, I haven't tried without timeout option. Can I actually do that?

Comment: @BingWang so the actual command would be subprocess.Popen([.......]) ?

Comment: Try p=Popen(...) followed by p.communicate(). But it seems a unknown SIGINT is your problem. You can try to define your own signal handler so it won't become KeyboardInterrupt. Or you can try specify a very long timeout so the subprocess module won't try to kill the java (Sorry I misread your original code which had no timeout).